# Matlab create matrix from data of other matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, creation

I have one matrix *u_test* that contains the data from my test set. 
It's formats is like that:

```
X  y  value
1  3  5.0
1  6  3.4
4  3  2.0
```

I want to create a matrix *test* from *u_test*, so that the value of the rating is in it correct position, for example:

```
   1    2    3    4    5    6

1:          5.0 
2:                         3.4
3:
4:          2.0
```

Is there a loop-free way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [SPARSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

```
out = sparse(u_test(:,1),u_test(:,2),u_test(:,3));
```

If the target size of the array should be `m-by-n`, you can write instead

```
out = sparse(u_test(:,1),u_test(:,2),u_test(:,3),m,n);
```

The good thing about using sparse is that it won't take too much space if the matrix `u_test` is large. However, if for some reason you cannot use sparse, convert to a full matrix using

```
outNotSparse = full(out);
```

Comment: Is there a way to force the matrix to have the size of 943 x 1682?

Comment: WOW! Now that's really fine. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

A fairly simple way would use the function [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A = [1 3 5; 1 6 2; 4 3 2];

maxima = max(A(:,1:2));
xsub = A(:,1);
ysub = A(:,2);

index = sub2ind(maxima, xsub, ysub);

C = zeros(maxima);
C(index) = A(:,3);
```

This parses out the three columns of `A` and converts the first two into linear indices. These are simply used to assign your data to the proper spots in `C`.